# @ManyToMany in Spring Boot (failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.Movie.actors, could not initialize proxy - no Session)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am currently trying out Spring boot and working with a test project, I ran into a problem with @ManyToMany-Relationships.

There should be movies, that can be saved and they can have multiple genres, actors and stuff like that. The actors can take part in many movies.

Now I can save the movie to the database, but for some reason I can only read out simple data, like the title or the year it was produced. If I try to print the genres to the command line, or the actors taking part, I get the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.Movie.actors, could not initialize proxy - no Session     at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:612)   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)     at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)   at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.get(PersistentBag.java:561)  at com.example.demo.MoviedbApplication.main(MoviedbApplication.java:75)`

Here's my Code:

```
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run = SpringApplication.run(MoviedbApplication.class, args); 
        GenreRepository genreRepository = run.getBean(GenreRepository.class);
    ActorRepository actorRepository = run.getBean(ActorRepository.class);
    AuthorRepository authorRepository = run.getBean(AuthorRepository.class);
    DirectorRepository directorRepository = run.getBean(DirectorRepository.class);
    MovieRepository movieRepository = run.getBean(MovieRepository.class);

    Movie theGodfather = new Movie();
    theGodfather.setTitle("Der Pate");
    theGodfather.setYear(1972);
    theGodfather.setOriginalTitle("The Godfather");
    theGodfather.setLengthInMinutes(175);
    theGodfather.setPlot("Der alternde Patriarch einer Verbrecherdynastie will die Herrschaft über sein geheimes Reich auf seinen widerwilligen Sohn übertragen.");
    theGodfather.setAge(16);

    List<Director> dirs = new ArrayList<>();
    dirs.add(new Director("Francis Ford Coppola"));

    List<Actor> acts = new ArrayList<>();
    acts.add(new Actor("Marlon Brando"));
    acts.add(new Actor("Al Pacino"));
    acts.add(new Actor("James Caan"));

    List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();
    genres.add(new Genre("Krimi"));
    genres.add(new Genre("Drama"));

    List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();
    authors.add(new Author("Mario Puzo"));
    authors.add(new Author("Francis Ford Coppola"));

    theGodfather.setActors(acts);
    theGodfather.setAuthors(authors);
    theGodfather.setDirectors(dirs);
    theGodfather.setGenres(genres);
    
    
    movieRepository.save(theGodfather);

    List<Movie> der_pate = movieRepository.findByTitle("Der Pate");

    Movie movie = der_pate.get(0);


    System.out.println("Test");
    System.out.println(movie.getYear());
    System.out.println(movie.getTitle());
    System.out.println(movie.getId());
    System.out.println(movie.getActors().get(0).getName());
    System.out.println(movie.getAuthors().get(0).getName());


@Entity
@Table(name="movies")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String originalTitle;
    private int year;
    private int age;
    private int lengthInMinutes;
    private String plot;
    private String linkToCover;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_genres",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
    )
    private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_actors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="actor_id")
    )
    private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_directors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "director_id")
    )
    private List<Director> directors = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movie_authors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    )
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();


@ManyToMany
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(
        name = "movie_genres",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id")
)
private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(
        name = "movie_actors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="actor_id")
)
private List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(
        name = "movie_directors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "director_id")
)
private List<Director> directors = new ArrayList<>();

@ManyToMany
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(
        name = "movie_authors",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
)
private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity @Table(name="Actor") public class Actor {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;

@ManyToMany
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

public Actor(String name) {
    this.name=name;
}`
```

What I already tried, was saving the actors and genres to their corresponding repositories, which lead to the following exception:

`detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.Actor; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.Actor`

I also fumbled around with eager fetching and stuff..Now I think, I have missed something quite essential here, so I am sorry, if this sounds like a beginners question..

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about the fetching type and session management. If you want to access actors associated with your movie, you need to set your fetch type as `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`in this situation.
Default fetch type is LAZY for ManyToMany relations.
Probably, your movie entity was detached from session after getting it from DB. So, even if you have line as movie.getActors() you get LazyInitializationException.
See for detail about hibernate lazy loading.
https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/lazy-loading-in-hibernate/

Comment: Tanks for your help :) I thought so too, maybe I'm doing something wrong, but if I add @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) to the actor class, I get the following Exception: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.demo.Actor; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : com.example.demo.Actor
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)

Comment: Add the constructor 'public Actor() {}'

Comment: Yes, you need to add default constructor and also have getter/setter method. Is it solved?

Comment: Oh thank you, I was wondering, if I need that. I'm working now, but I'll test it as soon as possible. The getters and setter I added of course.

Comment: @jungs When JPA fetch data form DB, It firstly create new Actor() object. Then It will use getter/setter method to set values from DB to object. So, yes we need to add default constructor. By the way, you can get rid of boilerplate code by using Lombok adding some annotation. https://projectlombok.org/

Comment: Thank you all very much for the instant and very kind help. It's working now, I added the eager fetching to the movie class and the default constructors. And that's all. (And thanks for the tip with Lombok)

Answer (score 0):

In your "findByTitle" method, you must load your ManyToMany relations as they are fetched LAZY by default. To load the collections, you can use the size() method. For example :

```
List<Movie> findByTitle(String title) {
   List<Movie> movies;
   //fetch movies

   //now load ManyToMany relationships
   for(var movie : movies) {
     movie.getActors().size();
     movie.getAuthors().size();
   }
   return movies;
}
```

I also suggest to use a Set instead of a List in your ManyToMany relationships